# is it possible to type the "spreadCall" method? a puzzle with conditional type and infer

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have an issue at work which I can summarize with this example: is it possible to fully type the following function?

```
    function spreadCall(f1, f2) {
        const args = f1();
        f2(...args);
    }
```

So we need f2 to accept exactly the same number of arguments (i.e. a tuple), with types in the same order, as the result of f1. I can't figure out a way to do this - the partial solution I can think of is enumerate several numbers of arguments, i.e.

```
    type Output<F> = 
         F extends ()=>[infer A0] ? (a0:A0)=>void :
         F extends ()=>[infer A0, infer A1] ? (a0:A0, a1:A1)=>void :
         F extends ()=>[infer A0, infer A1, infer A2] ? (a0:A0, a1:A1, a2:A2)=>void :
         never;
    // enumerate as many number of arguments as desired ^^

    function spreadCall<InputF>(f1:InputF, f2:Output<InputF>) {
        // ...
    }
```

Is there a way to do it which handles any number of arguments?

Comment: As long as the implementation isn't a array function, standard javascript functions expose the [arguments array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that has all the arguments.

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks, but my question is about typing, not implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a [generic rest parameter type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters) to do what you want:

```
function spreadCall<A extends any[]>(f1: () => A, f2: (...args: A) => any) {
    const args = f1();
    f2(...args);
}
```

The return of `f1` has to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) that matches the parameter types of the `f2` function:

```
declare function input(): [number, string]
declare function output(a: number, b: string): void;

spreadCall(input, output);
```